# How to merge timestamps that are only few seconds apart [Pandas]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe with shape 22341x3:

```
    tID   DateTime
0   1     2020-04-04 10:15:40
1   2     2020-04-04 10:15:56
2   2     2020-04-04 11:07:11
3   3     2020-04-04 11:08:14
4   3     2020-04-04 11:18:46
5   4     2020-04-04 11:23:56
6   5     2020-04-04 11:24:14
7   6     2020-04-04 11:29:12
8   7     2020-04-04 11:29:23
9   8     2020-04-04 11:34:23
```

Now I have to create a column called `merged_timestamp` that merges all the timestamps that are only a few seconds apart and give them a new number: `mtID`

So for example: if we consider `2020-04-04 10:15:40` as a reference, the timestamps with few seconds apart can be from `40` seconds until `44` seconds. They can have hours and minutes with a big gap as compared to the reference, but their seconds should be only few seconds apart in order to get merged.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I tried doing `dfd.resample('5s')[0:5]` where dfd is my dataframe. It gives me this error `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'`

Comment: you can resample the data with; https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Comment: @matman9 could you tell me how to implement it?

Comment: post the code that you have tried

Comment: @matman9 kindly see the question, I have edited it and have added what I tried.

Comment: you have a type error, you need to convert to datetime type, can do that with pd.to_datetime

Comment: @matman9 converted to datetime, still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resample works on the index, so make the datetime your index;

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
```

then you can resample with;

```
df.resample('5s').count()
```

or some other aggregation, not sure what you are trying to do. And then you could drop the rows that your not interested in.